# How does this use of "apply" in Coq work?

Tags: coq

I'm working my way through [software foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/). In the Chapter titled "Tactics", I'm able to prove this theorem in Coq:

> ```
> Theorem silly_ex :
>      (∀ n, evenb n = true → oddb (S n) = true) →
>      oddb 3 = true →
>      evenb 4 = true.
> Proof.
>   intros H1 H2. apply H2.
> Qed.
> ```

Even though I was able to get through the example, I don't understand how that is a solution. After performing `intros H1 H2` I'm left with proving that `evenb 4 = true`. The two hypotheses I have at this state are `H1 : forall n : nat, evenb n = true -> oddb (S n) = true` and `H2 : oddb 3 = true`.

How can `apply H2` solve this? Even knowing that 3 is odd doesn't fulfill the antecedent of the conditional.

Comment: Could it be a mistake, and the actual intention of that exercise was to have something like: "evenb 2 = true → oddb 3 = true"? Then you would "apply H1. apply H2", and it would be comparable to the worked examples given immediately before it. It would certainly be very odd pedagogically as it stands to leave the reader to work out the subtleties explained in the (very helpful) answer to this SO question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ask Coq to show you its proof object. Before `Qed`, type `Show Proof.`

```
(fun (_ : forall n : nat, evenb n = true -> oddb (S n) = true)
   (H2 : oddb 3 = true) => H2)
```

As you can see, `H1` is not used at all, and the goal *is* `H2`.

It comes from the [definition of `oddb` and `evenb`](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab27), the definition of `negb` and the definition of the natural numbers and the booleans.

> ```
> Definition oddb (n:nat) : bool := negb (evenb n).
> ```

- `oddb 3` is equal to `negb (evenb 3)` by the definition of `oddb` above.
- `evenb 3` is equal to `evenb (S (S (S O)))` by the definition of `3`. This is equal to `evenb (S O)` which is equal to `false` by the definition of `evenb`.
- Therefore `oddb 3 = negb false` which is in turn equal to `true` by the definition of `negb`.
- `evenb 4` is equal to `evenb (S (S (S (S O))))` by the definition of `4`. Applying the definition of `evenb` three shows that this is equal to `evenb (S (S O))`, to `evenb O`, and to `true`.

All of these equalities come from computation: if [$x$ reduces to $y$](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html#conversion-rules) then $x$ is equal to $y$ — this is the most basic form of equality¹. The reductions above use the $\beta$ rule (applying a lambda term to an argument), the $\delta$ rule (replacing a name by its definition) and the $\iota$ rule (applying a recursive function `fix …` and simplifying pattern matching).

Coq has a large set of [tactics to perform computations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#performing-computations), though they're only needed in advanced cases. For example, after `intros H1 H2`, you can ask it to expand `evenb` and `oddb`, but do nothing else.

```
cbv delta.
cbv delta in H2.
```

Integers like `3` and `4` are syntactic sugar, not named constants. `3` is `S (S (S O))`, not just some term that reduces to it. If you want to see everything that's going on, turn off pretty-printing of notations.

```
Unset Printing Notations.
```

(Use `Set Printing Notations.` to turn them back on.)

You can watch the goal being reduced to its value.

```
cbn iota. cbn beta. cbn iota. cbn beta. cbn iota. cbn beta. cbn iota. cbn beta. cbn iota.
```

Of course you don't need to guide Coq so much, this is just if you want to see all the steps. You can simply ask Coq to compute as much as possible. Just after `intros H1 H2`, run

```
compute. compute in H2.
```

and you'll see that both `H2` and the goal simplify to `true = true`.

In this particular case there's no simpler way to go from `H2` to the goal than to fully calculate both. If you continue the tutorial a bit, you'll get to recursive proofs, where it's very common to have similar hypotheses and a similar goal, but with a variable instead of constants like `3`. There you would typically combine `H1` and `H2` together (but here `H1` is not particularly interesting — since you're proving something about `evenb`, you'd want the an implication of the form `oddb … -> evenb …` rather than `evenb … -> oddb …`).

¹  <sub>In a certain sense, it's the only form of equality.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me!